# how to pass reference of global variables in express 4.*

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, global-variables

I have a variable say 
var `data = {}` in a file data.js;

`module.exports = data;`

if I am importing this file in another page... I get only the value of variable.. how could I get its **reference** ?

I mean if I change something in this other file, it should reflect in the base file i.e `data.js`

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you modifying your `data= {}` variable at runtime ?

Comment: yes I am .. I have no problem in restarting the server once the its updated

Comment: your `module.exports` executes once when your script initialises and will import only those values whatever there were at that time. You'll have to figure out some other mechanism like shared service/class between components through which you can read/write your data object.

Comment: is it possible to make it a global variable through out the app. so that i dont have to import it but just access and ammend it @abhishekkannojia

Answer (score 0):

If you want your changes to be persistent in the original data.js file then you will have to achieve it by just changing the values in your code.

For example, when I have:

```
var x = 10;
```

in my program and later I do:

```
x = 20;
```

then the original place where it was 10 wouldn't be changed in the source code. The same is here.

What you can use is something like:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-file-db
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/lowdb
- http://www.tingodb.com/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-node-db
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat-file-db
- http://lokijs.org/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite